# How to set icon size in Xamarin forms?]

Tags: xamarin.forms, icons, toolbar

I have added an icon in Xamarin toolbar. But I saw that the icons looks so small in emulator & still can't change the toolbar item icon size. My source code in XAML page is given in below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage[enter image description here][1]
    x:Class="IDIS.HomePage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
            Icon="home1.png"
            Order="Primary"
            Priority="0"
            Text="Home" />
        <ToolbarItem
            Icon="noti1.png"
            Order="Primary"
            Priority="1"
            Text="Notification" />
        <ToolbarItem
            Icon="rating1.png"
            Order="Primary"
            Priority="2"
            Text="Rating" />
        <ToolbarItem
            Icon="feedback1.png"
            Order="Primary"
            Priority="3"
            Text="Feedback" />
        <ToolbarItem
            Order="Secondary"
            Priority="0"
            Text="Item 2" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

Screenshot of my output attached

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRXFy.png)

Answer (score 2):

First create an icon of size, for say 512*512, and then use [this](https://appicon.co/) website to generate the icons of appropriate sizes. You will see that there are two folders after unzipping the downloaded file from the website. One is android and another is iOS. Copy and paste images from android folder to its corresponding resource folders (drawable-hpdi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drwable-xxxhdpi) and also copy and paste the three files in iOS folder (image, image@2x, image@3x) to the Resource folder in iOS project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll actually have to change the images sizes - here's sample of what I use :

You can get a good sample app here [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/1b7200791931f33c94206822a69644ca820bb0dc/src/Mobile/eShopOnContainers) from Xamarin guys

**Android**

**drawable-hdpi**

- eShopOnContainers.Droid/Resources/drawable-hdpi/app_settings.png
- 256x 256

**drawable-xhdpi**

- eShopOnContainers.Droid/Resources/drawable-xhdpi/app_settings.png
- 341 x 341

**drawable-xxhdpi**

- eShopOnContainers.Droid/Resources/drawable-xxhdpi/app_settings.png
- 512 x 512

**IOS**

- eShopOnContainers.iOS/Resources/app_settings.png
- 44 x 44
- eShopOnContainers.iOS/Resources/app_settings@2x.png
- 44 x 44
- eShopOnContainers.iOS/Resources/app_settings@3x.png
- 66 x 66